# Rescale a matrix in [0-1]

Tags: correlation, independence

I have a dependency matrix as follows:

```
      Y     X1     X2     X3     X4     X5
Y  154.52 154.52 363.28  86.04  98.42 105.21
X1 154.52 154.52 363.28  86.04  98.42 105.21
X2 363.28 363.28 598.73 276.12 287.94 291.42
X3  86.04  86.04 276.12 131.01 102.61 111.25
X4  98.42  98.42 287.94 102.61 164.29 109.33
X5 105.21 105.21 291.42 111.25 109.33 178.63
```

where I know that `X1` and `X2` are transformation of `Y` (`X1=0.5*Y and X2=Y^2`). Is there any way to scale a matrix like this into [0,1] where diagonal will be 1 and all other measures will be scaled according to them? I want to create a correlation-like matrix to see the dependencies between variables. All my efforts, result in values >1, e.g., in `(Y,X2)`.

Comment: Hi Nick, welcome to the site! What's a dependency matrix?

Comment: Hey @JohnMadden, just a matrix measuring how dependent with each other are the elements. For example in the given matrix in first row you can tell that Y has strongest/more dependence relationshio with X1 and X2 compared to X3,X4, and X5.

Comment: I suppose I'm asking what formula you're using for dependence.

Comment: It's a Kernel-based formula that unfortunately, I'm not allowed to share. Basically, each Y and Xj, j=1,2,..,5, (Y,Xj) combination generates a matrix. Then, I find the eigenvalues of each matrix. What you see here in each element, is the first eigenvalue that matrix (Y,Xj) produced

Comment: OK thanks. Does dividing each $a_{i,j}$ by $\sqrt{a_{i,i}a_{j,j}}$ do the trick?

Comment: Do you mean, for example for `a13=363.28` that corresponds to combination `Y` with `X_2` to do `363.28/ sqrt(154.52*598.73)`. Because this will result in 1.19. I have created a similar way, but trying to scale it in [0,1] if possible

Comment: Oh I see, the problem is that your "dependence" is not positive definite. A simple approach would be to first project your dependence matrix into the space of positive semidefinite matrices by thresholding all negative eigenvalues to zero, and then to proceed with the normalization I suggested. It's hard to say how well this will work without knowing more about your approach and application, though.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion and efforts, however the dependence matrix is positive define since i use a kernel approach and select the first eigenvalue (always positive).

Comment: I'm talking about the matrix you have posted in the answer. Since positive definite matrices are diagonally dominant, your matrix is not positive definite. Calling something a "kernel" doesn't make it positive definite :). In particular, the eigenvalues of the matrix you have posted are  1.301633e+03  1.094361e+02  6.213426e+01  3.842291e+01 -3.410605e-13 -1.299261e+02

Comment: (diagonal dominance is actually not the property I'm thinking of, but the substantive point remains)

Comment: If you are asking how to turn a covariance matrix into a correlation matrix in R then if `V` is the covariance matrix `cov2cor(V)` is the corresponding correlation matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn a covariance matrix into a correlation matrix, we divide each element $a_{i,j}$ by $\sqrt{ a_{i,i}a_{j,j}}$. The covariance of two variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ is bounded by the geometric mean of the standard deviations of $X_1$ and $X_2$, which is why this will map to $[0,1]$. But your function violates this property, and the mapping doesn't hold.

I'm not sure what the best option is to remedy that. But one that I can think of is to find a *projection* of your dependence measure onto the set of measures which are *positive semidefinite*. Positive semidefiniteness is a property that implies not only the bivariate geometric mean property that we were just discussing but much more, and is basically a mathematical description of the possible covariance matrices that there are (which happens to also be the possible norms that there are).

A positive semidefinite matrix is typically defined as a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ such that $\underset{\mathbf{u}\in\mathbb{R}^{N}}{\min} \mathbf{u}^\top\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u} \geq 0$. But for our conversation, is best characterized as a symmetric matrix with positive eigenvalues. This is because this is the characterization that allows for projection:

$$ 
\textrm{proj}_{psd}(\mathbf{A}) = \underset{\mathbf{A'} \textrm{ is positive semidefinite}}{\min} \Vert \mathbf{A}-\mathbf{A}' \Vert_2 = \mathbf{A}^+
$$

That equation in words: Given some matrix $\mathbf{A}$, its projection onto the set of positive semidefinite matrices is the positive semidefinite matrix which is closest to it. The way to solve this projection problem is $\mathbf{A}^+$ which is matrix function notation, and is indicating that we should apply the positive part function (aka the relu function) to the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$, or in other words simply to take $\mathbf{A}$'s negative eigenvalues and replace them with 0.

Let's take a look at your matrix:

```
A <- matrix(c(154.52, 154.52, 363.28,  86.04,  98.42, 105.21,
154.52, 154.52, 363.28,  86.04,  98.42, 105.21,
363.28, 363.28, 598.73, 276.12, 287.94, 291.42,
86.04,  86.04, 276.12, 131.01, 102.61, 111.25,
98.42,  98.42, 287.94, 102.61, 164.29, 109.33,
105.21, 105.21, 291.42, 111.25, 109.33, 178.63), nrow = 6)

eigen(A)
```

yields:

```
eigen() decomposition
$values
[1]  1.301633e+03  1.094361e+02  6.213426e+01  3.842291e+01 -3.410605e-13 -1.299261e+02

$vectors
           [,1]       [,2]        [,3]        [,4]          [,5]       [,6]
[1,] -0.3457036  0.4474150 -0.03401383  0.03916468 -7.071068e-01  0.4214475
[2,] -0.3457036  0.4474150 -0.03401383  0.03916468  7.071068e-01  0.4214475
[3,] -0.7117501  0.1079146  0.02017398 -0.05867608  1.110223e-16 -0.6913150
[4,] -0.2734790 -0.4104533 -0.01041495 -0.82117348 -3.053113e-16  0.2868850
[5,] -0.2940345 -0.4179128  0.73849747  0.37677192  5.273559e-16  0.2270617
[6,] -0.3051929 -0.4948446 -0.67215485  0.42095892  8.881784e-16  0.1816247
```

plotting:

```
plot(eigen(A)$values)
abline(h=0)
```

[image: negative eigenvalue]

We see that, according to your dependency measure, there's perfect correlation in one dimension (eigenvalue 5 is numerically zero, and is there because the first two rows are the same) and we see that it has a negative eigenvalue, which our projection procedure is going to wipe away.

Here's that scaling from covariance to correlation:

```
root_scale <- function(A) {
    sd <- sqrt(diag(A))
    for (i in 1:nrow(A)) {
        for (j in 1:nrow(A)) {
            A[i,j] <- A[i,j] / (sd[i]*sd[j])
        }
    }
    return(A)
}

root_scale(A)
```

We see that you have values outside of $[0,1]$, as you noted.

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.1943555 0.6047221 0.6177112 0.6332679
[2,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.1943555 0.6047221 0.6177112 0.6332679
[3,] 1.1943555 1.1943555 1.0000000 0.9858938 0.9180808 0.8911004
[4,] 0.6047221 0.6047221 0.9858938 1.0000000 0.6994101 0.7272280
[5,] 0.6177112 0.6177112 0.9180808 0.6994101 1.0000000 0.6381997
[6,] 0.6332679 0.6332679 0.8911004 0.7272280 0.6381997 1.0000000
```

So now let's compute the projection onto the set of positive semidefinite matrices:

```
proj_psd <- function(A) {
    Aed <- eigen(A)
    ev <- Aed$values
    ev <- pmax(ev, 0)
    Apd <- Aed$vectors %*% diag(ev) %*% t(Aed$vectors)
    return(Apd )
}
```

Our new matrix is:

```
Apd <- proj_psd(A)
Apd
```

yields:

```
    [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]
[1,] 177.5972 177.5972 325.4257 101.7490 110.8532 115.1552
[2,] 177.5972 177.5972 325.4257 101.7490 110.8532 115.1552
[3,] 325.4257 325.4257 660.8238 250.3520 267.5454 275.1065
[4,] 101.7490 101.7490 250.3520 141.7033 111.0735 118.0198
[5,] 110.8532 110.8532 267.5454 111.0735 170.9886 114.6882
[6,] 115.1552 115.1552 275.1065 118.0198 114.6882 182.9159
```

Which obeys the scaling rule:

```
root_scale(Apd)
```

yields:

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.9499284 0.6413897 0.6361312 0.6389102
[2,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.9499284 0.6413897 0.6361312 0.6389102
[3,] 0.9499284 0.9499284 1.0000000 0.8181224 0.7959229 0.7912837
[4,] 0.6413897 0.6413897 0.8181224 1.0000000 0.7135703 0.7330596
[5,] 0.6361312 0.6361312 0.7959229 0.7135703 1.0000000 0.6484988
[6,] 0.6389102 0.6389102 0.7912837 0.7330596 0.6484988 1.0000000
```

**Comments:**

1. This is a mathematical transformation that gets you the property that you want without disturbing your input too much. But I can't guarantee that it does exactly what you're looking for without knowing more about your problem.
2. Question to the Community: In a way, this is a longer projection than the OP asked for: Positive-definiteness is a stronger property than the geometric mean property. Is there an efficient way to calculate the projection onto geometric-mean-bounded functions? By a similar token, perhaps we should have done the projection on the "precorrelation matrices" (aka the image of root_scale).
3. As G. Gronthendieck pointed out, it seems my function root_scale is implemented as cov2cor in R.

**TL;DR** Turn your matrix into something that behaves like a covariance matrix then apply the standard scaling.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! It is very helpful.